# Which one is correct "delivered to" or "delivered at"?

Tags: meaning

Should I say Food delivered to your doorsteps or Food delivered at your doorsteps?

Comment: In colloquial U.S. English, the phrase  "at [or _to_] your doorstep[s]" is almost always singular ("doorstep"), although I see no objective reason why unless _doorstep_ is being used in the sense of "one footstep away from your door" instead of "the steps leading up to your door." I'd be interested in an explanation for this preference, if anyone knows what it is. Also, is "to/at your doorsteps" the normal U.K. English form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Delivered to* is the more correct usage.

If you are saying "to" suggesting where the food traveled, e.g. "It traveled from A to B", then the food is *delivered to B*.

If you are saying "to" suggesting the recipient, e.g. "It was given to A. Citizen", then the food is *delivered to A. Citizen*.

*Delivered at* may be technically correct but sounds wrong in the context you provided. You would say "delivered at" when speaking in the broader sense of when/where the delivery took place rather than the specifics of the delivery itself, e.g. "The food will be delivered *at* midday", "The food was delivered *at* the festival".